# How can I get the attribute in androidviewclient

Tags: android, python, androidviewclient

How can I get the dump attribute in androidviewclient. 
for example, I want to get the attribute value of 'selected'.Please help!!

[android attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqMih.png)

Comment: This answer may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693656/is-it-possible-with-androidviewclient-to-obtain-and-print-button-status

Comment: @MaDu_LK thanks for the reply, I can get the button or item Text by androidviewclient - gettext(), But I want to get the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `dump -a` to dump all attributes you can see something like this (filtering `selected`):

```
$ dump -a | grep selected

        View[ class=android.widget.TextView index=2 selected=false checked=false clickable=false package=com.android.deskclock text=Tomorrow long-clickable=false enabled=true bounds=((36, 1455), (254, 1520)) content-desc= focusable=true focused=false uniqueId=id/no_id/29 checkable=false resource-id=com.android.deskclock:id/upcoming_instance_label password=false class=android.widget.TextView scrollable=false ]   parent=android.widget.LinearLayout
```

then, you can find any View using whatever attribute is appropriate for you case and invoke `View.getSelected()` as in this example:

```
com_android_deskclock___id_upcoming_instance_label = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise(u'Tomorrow')
print "selected=", com_android_deskclock___id_upcoming_instance_label.getSelected()
```

this was generated using [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra), which is an excellent way of creating your tests or scripts automatically. I just added the `print` line.